# by passing one id get two rows in another table

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

i have 2 tables

1st table:

```
review(r_id, r_name, r_AttachmentId1,r_AttachmentId2) 

1,11,21 [11 is file xyz.txt, 21 is file abc.txt]
```

2nd table:

```
attachmentinformation (a_Attachmentid,a_AttachmentFileName,a_AttachmentFileExtension)

(11,xyz,txt)
(21,pqr,txt)
```

and for every attachment in 1st table will have one record in 2nd table for example , r_AttachmentId1(11) in first table have detail info. in 2nd table

want to achieve: with one sql query is by passing r_id want to retrieve a_AttachmentFileName for both file.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at JOINs:

```
SELECT a.a_AttachmentFileName
FROM review r
JOIN attachmentinformation a
ON a.a_Attachmentid IN (r.r_AttachmentId1, r.r_AttachmentId2)
WHERE r.r_id = 1;
```